# Coax cable with CAN bus

Tags: cables, can, termination

I got some Microchip CAN transceivers and some Stellaris [Launchpads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430_Launchpad) from [TI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments). I would like to learn how [CAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) works. It looks very nice for what I want to do (one controller per room, controls lights, vents, etc.)

The first thought was to use [Cat 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) for the data line. But I don't understand how I am supposed to tie the connector to the twisted pair (unless I just do a pass through, two [RJ45s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C) for each node).

While 60 Ω is the impedance recommended for CAN, can I use 50 or 75 Ω coax cable? Googling it didn't yield anything much for me, nothing definite.

So I can just run a coax cable and [T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_connector) it off instead of passing through (or splicing the cable I guess)?

Coax seems a nice clean way to do it, but since it's not talked about I am missing something, I imagine.

Comment: 120 Ohms not 60 ohms termination resistance is required for CAN!

Comment: I thought it was 2 paralleled 120 ohm resistors

Comment: @MichaelStyln- It's two 60 resistors **in series**, with the center often tied to Vcc/2

Comment: @FakeName, two 60 ohm resistors in series, possibly with the center tied to Vcc/2, with such a termination at each end of the cable yields a net 60 ohm differential impedance on the bus.  An ohmmeter test on a powered-down bus is the first test I do when things aren't working right to assess under- or over-termination.

Comment: @HikeOnPast - You're missing the difference between terminating a transmission line (what you're doing here), and the static resistance of the system. There is an excellent Microchip App-Note here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00228a.pdf

Comment: @FakeName, I guess I'm still missing it.  There were no search hits for "static" in your link and the only mention of "resistance" is in Table 1.  What is "static resistance" vice 60 ohm net differential impedance on a properly terminated bus?

Comment: I've just (last week) made a CAN bus boosterpack for Stellaris LauncPad, you might want to check it out https://github.com/Miceuz/can-boosterpack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CAN bus uses differential signalling.  CAN is wired with twisted pair.  Have a look at the [standard CAN pinouts](http://www.interfacebus.com/Can_Bus_Connector_Pinout.html).  Notice that one of them is for the RJ-45 connector.

[CAN cabling guide.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517053504/https://copleycontrols.com/motion/pdf/CAN-Bus.pdf) *(archive.org)*

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I will do the standard method so I can avoid trouble.  Thanks for your time